# Rendering Image without makign the Event Dispatch Thread wait?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, event-dispatch-thread

I am rendering a BufferedImage on a numuber of threads. When I start those threads I am calling wait on the Event Dispatch Thread so that it actually draws the image only when all rendering threads have sent the notify signal.

This is what happens in the EDT:

```
synchronized (this)
    {
        while(threadsCompleted<RENDERING_THREADS){
            try{
                this.wait();
            }catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        threadsCompleted = 0;
    }
g2.drawImage(image);
```

and this is what happens when a thread finishes running:

```
synchronized (MyPanel.this){
            threadsCompleted++;
            MyPanel.this.notify();
        }
```

My question is: is there a way to make the call on drawImage wait for the threads to finish without actually stopping the EDT work? is there a way so that in those milliseconds that the rendering goes on, the user can actually interact with the UI, thus Event Dispatch Thread?

Comment: Move\ the first synchronized code into its own thread, and call the drawImage method using a SwingUtilities invokeLater Runnable run method.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use the concurrency constructs in `java.util.concurrent` and to use a thread which waits for all the others to complete, like this:

```
public class ImageRenderer implements Runnable
{
    private final CountDownLatch latch;

    public ImageRenderer(CountDownLatch latch)
    {
        this.latch = latch;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            // code...
        } finally
        {
            latch.countDown();
        }
    }
}

public class Waiter implements Runnable
{
    private final CountDownLatch latch;

    public Waiter(CountDownLatch latch)
    {
        this.latch = latch;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            latch.await();
            // rendering has now finished.
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                // do something with the image on the EDT
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```